# read_sql_table in Dask returns NoSuchTableError

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, dask, pydoc

I have a read_sql using pandas and it works fine. However, when I tried to re-create the same dataframe under Dask using the same logic. It gives me NoSuchTableError. I know for sure the table exists in my SQL database.

pandas #works:

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd

sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table"
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};\
                             SERVER=my_server;\
                             DATABASE=db_name;\
                             Trusted_Connection=yes;")
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params)
df = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
print(df.head())
```

Since Dask is using the full URL from sqlalchemy, I also tried to re-create the same connection in sqlalchemy and it works. It just puzzles me why it does not work in Dask.

sqlalchemy #works:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://my_server/db_name\
         ?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')

result = engine.execute("select * from my_table")

for row in result:
    print(row[0])
```

Dask #NoSuchTableError:

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa
import dask.dataframe as dd
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import make_url

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};\
                             SERVER=my_server;\
                             DATABASE=db_name;\
                             Trusted_Connection=yes;")
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
url = make_url(conn_str)
df = dd.read_sql_table('my_table', url, index_col='ID')
print(df.head())
```

Has anyone came across the same/similar issue? Any thought is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried passing `conn_str` instead of the reformatted `url`?

Comment: I did and it gives me the same error! :(

Comment: How about `pd.read_sql_table("my_table", engine)` ?

Comment: pandas works fine using `pd.read_sql()`. However, as far as I know, under Dask, the URL has to be a full sqlalchemy URL rather than an engine.

Comment: @Xwnola any update on this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

without knowing further details about how your SQL Server is set up, I believe this will be SQL Server specific from the Dask documentation, you need to provide the  `schema=` keyword, like this:

```
dftest = dd.read_sql_table(table="table_name_only", uri=uri, index_col="somekey", schema="schema_name", divisions=[1,2,3])
```

Note that `uri` here is the SQLAlchemy string, not a connection object.

[https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDM0U.png)